# Dynamic Value in SQL Select Partition

Tags: sql, oracle

As the title say, is it possible to put a dynamic value in Paritition during **SELECT**?
I've been searching around for the answer in stack and i can't find a solution to this.

Example

```
SELECT
    TB1.TB_ID,
    TB1.EFF_DATE
FROM
    TABLE TABLE1 PARTITION (D20191230) TB1, TABLE2 PARTITION (D20191230) TB2
WHERE
    TB1.EFF_DATE >= TO_DATE(:p_req_date, 'yyyymmdd') 
AND 
    TB1.EFF_DATE < TO_DATE(:p_req_date, 'yyyymmdd') + 1
AND
    TB1.TB_ID = TB2.TB_ID
```

Is it possible to turn Partition value into

```
('D' + :p_req_date)
```

where :p_req_date will also be in yyyymmdd

I've tried concat and subquery but nothing seems to click.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank You!!

Comment: Why *do you need to address the partition explicitely*? Does not *partition pruning* work for you?

Comment: How is the table partitioned? Why not simply include the partition key in the WHERE clause and let Oracle do the job? This sounds overly complicated for something that Oracle can do automatically.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Sorry for the long reply, because this SQL is used for daily jobs on D+(sysdate) partition to improve query speed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name english wasnt quite my first language and i had a problem understanding your comment, do you imply that i can actually put the partition key on where? if i can that would be really helpful!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh also the table is partitioned by EFF_DATE

Comment: @Karen see may new answer, where I address what I thing is the *root cause* of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **dynamic query** for it.

I have the table `stu_data` and it has the partition named `SYS_P389`, the following is the example of how to use the dynamic name of the partition using `execute immediate` (dynamic SQL)

> ```
> SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
> SQL>
> SQL> DECLARE
>   2      LV_ROLL_NO   STU_DATA.ROLL_NO%TYPE;
>   3      LV_P3898     VARCHAR2(100) := 'P3898';
>   4  BEGIN
>   5      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max(roll_no) from stu_data partition (SYS_'
>   6                        || LV_P3898
>   7                        || ')'
>   8      INTO LV_ROLL_NO;
>   9      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('output: ' || LV_ROLL_NO);
>  10  END;
>  11  /
> output: 1
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Dear lord and i thought this isnt possible, one more thing, this works with cursor right? @Tejash

Comment: And also this might sound like a stretch but is it possible without **PL/SQL**?

Comment: @Karen, Yes, This will work with Cursor also and Execute Immediate is part of PL/SQL, So this cannot be run without PL/SQL.

Comment: @Karen: the proper way to do this "dynamically" is to use the partition key in the WHERE clause and forget about the `partition` keyword, PL/SQL or dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the feature of *partition pruning* that is crutial for large partitioned tables. Check the concepts in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/partition-pruning.html#GUID-E677C85E-C5E3-4927-B3DF-684007A7B05D) first.

To demonstrate the *partition pruning* the following setup will be used

```
create table TABLE1 
   PARTITION BY RANGE (EFF_DATE)
   INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY'))
( 
   PARTITION p_init VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
)
as
select rownum tb_id, 
       date'2019-01-01' + (rownum -1) as EFF_DATE
from dual connect by level <= 365;
```

The table is *interval partitioned* with one day partitions on the column `EFF_DATE`. The `TABLE2` is created identically.

Now let's look on the execution plan of your query, referencing the tables and not the partitions:

```
SELECT
    TB1.TB_ID,
    TB1.EFF_DATE
FROM TABLE1 TB1, TABLE2 TB2
WHERE
    TB1.EFF_DATE >= TO_DATE(:p_req_date, 'yyyymmdd')
AND 
    TB1.EFF_DATE < TO_DATE(:p_req_date, 'yyyymmdd') + 1
AND
    TB1.TB_ID = TB2.TB_ID;
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) how to produce the following execution plan.

```
Plan hash value: 3726328978

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |        |     2 |    32 |  3724   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  FILTER                    |        |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                |        |     2 |    32 |  3724   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|        |     2 |    24 |  1849   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TABLE1 |     2 |    24 |  1849   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   5 |    PARTITION RANGE ALL     |        |   365 |  1460 |  1874   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TABLE2 |   365 |  1460 |  1874   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd')+1>TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd'))
   2 - access("TB1"."TB_ID"="TB2"."TB_ID")
   4 - filter("TB1"."EFF_DATE"<TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd')+1 AND 
              "TB1"."EFF_DATE">=TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd'))
```

The relevant part is in the columns `Pstart` and `Pstop`. You see that in the `TABLE1`  **only one partition** is accessed. `KEY - KEY`  means that the partition is not fixed (you used bind variables), but only data from one partition will be scanned.

The problem is on table `TABLE2` which is accessed fully (all partitions).

*Why?*

Oracle does not know that *the rows with the same `ID` in both tables have the same effective date*.

This is exect what you want to *teach* Oracle by passing the identical partition names in the join.

Much better way is to do in the `WHERE` clause by adding the predicate on `EFF_DATE` for the `TABLE2`

```
SELECT
    TB1.TB_ID,
    TB1.EFF_DATE
FROM TABLE1 TB1, TABLE2 TB2
WHERE
    TB1.EFF_DATE >= TO_DATE(:p_req_date, 'yyyymmdd')
AND 
    TB1.EFF_DATE < TO_DATE(:p_req_date, 'yyyymmdd') + 1
AND
    TB1.TB_ID = TB2.TB_ID
AND 
    TB2.EFF_DATE >= TO_DATE(:p_req_date, 'yyyymmdd')  /* filter for EFF_DATE in TABLE2 added */
AND 
    TB2.EFF_DATE < TO_DATE(:p_req_date, 'yyyymmdd') + 1;
```

Now Oracle *knows* that in both tables only one  partition should be accessed.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |        |     2 |    48 |  3724   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  FILTER                    |        |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                |        |     2 |    48 |  3724   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|        |     2 |    24 |  1849   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TABLE1 |     2 |    24 |  1849   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   5 |    PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|        |     2 |    24 |  1874   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TABLE2 |     2 |    24 |  1874   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd')+1>TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd'))
   2 - access("TB1"."TB_ID"="TB2"."TB_ID")
   4 - filter("TB1"."EFF_DATE"<TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd')+1 AND 
              "TB1"."EFF_DATE">=TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd'))
   6 - filter("TB2"."EFF_DATE"<TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd')+1 AND 
              "TB2"."EFF_DATE">=TO_DATE(:P_REQ_DATE,'yyyymmdd'))
```

So you solved your task **without a need of dynamic SQL**, which is always the prefered way to go.

Comment: First of all dear lord, i thought this wasnt necessary. But then i implemented your idea and give it a go, it cuts thru 160.000 cost (<- F10 on SQL Developer) all the way to 83.000. While this isnt the answer of my question. This definitely helped with my case. Thank you so much for this!!

Answer (score 0):

In general you should put condition into `WHERE` clause instead of using the `PARTITION` clause.

Anyway, in case you really like to specify the partition then I would recommend the `PARTITION FOR` clause in order to be independent from partition name which is random by default. You should also prefer the ANSI join syntax.

```
sqlstr := 
'SELECT TB1.TB_ID, TB1.EFF_DATE
FROM TABLE1 PARTITION FOR (DATE '''||TO_CHAR(p_req_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||''') TB1
   JOIN TABLE2 PARTITION FOR (DATE '''||TO_CHAR(p_req_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||''') TB2 ON TB1.TB_ID = TB2.TB_ID
WHERE TB1.EFF_DATE >= :aDate
   AND TB1.EFF_DATE < :bDate';

OPEN cur FOR sqlstr USING p_req_date, p_req_date + 1;
```

I hope data type of `p_req_date` is a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) rather than a string. Otherwise you should convert it to proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` value.